# How to clear the keyboard autocomplete suggestions

Tags: auto-correct, dictionary

I need to completely clear the autocomplete words my Sony Ericsson Xperia arc has learned. I used it for entering some random letter combinations (CAPTCHA entries) and now they are part of the autocomplete for some important prefixes. How can this be done? Looked in the settings screen but no luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is positioned high in Google, so I'm gonna paste my solution here. I own a **Sonyericsson Xperia Arc S** and the Personal Dictionary list was empty.

The way to go was to go into the **app listing (all apps)**, find the **Xperia Keyboard** service and **Clear Data**.

It resets every keyboard configuration, but it's how it works.

Comment: On some devices (even Xperia ones), it's, "International Keyboard".

Answer (score 4):

You can clear learned words under `Settings --> Language and keyboard --> User dictionary`. Long press on the learned word and then edit or delete.

Comment: This solution does not apply to recent Sony devices unfortunately. They can learn words without being added specifically to the user (personal) dictionary, which is what the OP and myself had a problem with.

Answer (score 3):

Go to setting ---> Controls ---> Language and inputs ---> keyboard and input methods --> (setting icon) behind your keyboard type -- > predictive text --> clear personal data .. :) 
That's all :)

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the words by Setting:Language and Keyboard:User Dictionary works only for words you've saved manually.  To unlearn words that were learned automatically, you need to go the the app that drives your text input and clear the data for that app.  For example, on my Casio Commando, I go to my list of apps, click on XT9 Text Input app and click on "Clear Data.

Answer (score 0):

**For xperia**

---

Go to setting ---> Controls ---> Language and inputs ---> keyboard and input methods --->Select the Keyboard you using (eg., Xperia Keyboard)--->Settings icon--->>Use my writting style--->In My Words you can delete the words you want to remove or you can go to Clear data to clear all your words.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the autocomplete suggestions and be able to type the message: **double tap on the word you are trying to write**, than try to finish writing your word.

Answer (score 0):

Open any app like mail or message and start typing, predicted text will be displayed. Just long press it and select remove from prediction.. Done