# How do I clear learned words?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clear the keyboard autocomplete suggestions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20457/how-to-clear-the-keyboard-autocomplete-suggestions)

I want to clear the learned words on my Android 2.3.4 phone. They are not found on the User Dictionary but I can see them being suggested whenever I'm typing.

Comment: How is this an exact duplicate? The linked supposed duplicate only had one answer and the answer doesn't even work since, as I stated above, the learned words aren't found on the User Dictionary at all. I think it's a little different since he didn't confirm if it existed in the User Dictionary or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using swipe, go to **settings**> **locale and text**> **swype settings** and then click on **reset swype's dictionary**

Also you can navigate to **Settings** > **Applications** > **Manage Applications**. Then once there, you will need to scroll down and find the keyboard app. Click on that, and then tap the “**Clear Data**” button.

when the list of learned words appears, long press on one and you may be given the option to forget it. This works on samsung galaxy note 3.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But shouldn't there be a way to clear just the learned words instead of the everything including the settings?